# PDF: A button to add a row of text fields on fillable form

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe, fillable

The original thread:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/have-a-button-in-adobe-acrobat-that-adds-a-row-of-columns-then-adds-another-row-below-it/m-p/14250883#M439889

The script works to create fillable text fields, however I need to limit the number of rows it creates. Below is the javascript:

```
var myRows = new Array();
var rowCounter = 1;

function addRow() {

if (rowCounter >= 5) {
return;
}

myRows[rowCounter - 1] = "Row" + rowCounter + ".Column1";
myRows[rowCounter] = "Row" + rowCounter + ".Column2";
myRows[rowCounter + 1] = "Row" + rowCounter + ".Column3";
myRows[rowCounter + 2] = "Row" + rowCounter + ".Column4";


var w = 144;
var h = 18;
var wGap = 6;

for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {  // Adjust the number of rows per line (here set to 2 for 4 columns)

    var coordinates = [10, 700 + (rowCounter * 24)]; // Adjust the vertical position for each new row
    var afields = [coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[0] + w, coordinates[1] - h];

    for (var i = 0; i < myRows.length; i++) {
        this.addField(myRows[i], "text", 0, afields);
        afields[0] += (w + wGap);
        afields[2] += (w + wGap);
    }
    rowCounter += -1;
}
}
```

The button functions under actions: Mouse Up > Execute a Menu Item > 'Run a javascript':

`addRow();`

Right now it seems to create an infinite number of text field and need to limit the rows to at least 5 rows. I would like to also add a button that would delete row(s) if too many is created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove fields. The appropriate Doc Object method is called

```
removeField()
```

To remove the last row of fields, find out its `rowCounter` value, and use this method for the according fields. As you have a separator in the field name, it may be sufficient to just pass `"Row" + rowCounter` as argument instead of deleting the individual fields.

FWIW, a little advice: Because the number of rows value should not rely on a value in memory, you might add a hidden field where you store the `rowCounter` value, and update it every time when you do some modifications with the rows.

Comment: Thanks Max, but I have to admit, I'm a bit less than a novice when it comes to Javascript and trying my best to understand everything you're saying. I added the section of trying to limit to 5 rows to the code and it's not working. I'm sure what you're saying is correct, I just need to figure out what you mean.